# Python, TCP sendall

Tags: python

How can I send to a specific client? TCP Server can send to all clients

I store the `sendip` and `sendport`, obtained using this code:

```
clientssendback = []
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
clientssendback.append(address)

for x in clientssendback:
    sendip = str(x[0])
    sendport = str(x[1])

    clientsocket.sendall(bytes("hello", "utf-8"), (sendip, sendport))
```

I'll have so I can send it to all client there are loged into the server.
Can some one help me with that? Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Calling `.sendall()` on a client socket (as returned by `.accept()`) sends only to that specific client - you don't need to specify an address or port number.  Sending to all clients requires looping over all of the currently-active client sockets, and calling `.sendall()` on each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a few notes:

1. the accept() function returns a tuple. the first is the connection made between the server and client. it is not the client's socket.
2. this means that you establish a unique connection between every client and the server when you accept him. the transfering of data happens through this coonection.
3. first you need to save these coonections in a list, and loop between them, and send the message to each client

```
import socket    
connections = []   
server_socket = socket.socket() # by default it's TCP/IP
server_socket.bind((ip_address, port)
server_socket.listen(20) 
conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
connections.append(conn)
```

now you now how to establish a connection and save it in a list. now lets send a message which is "hello" to all clients

```
for connection in connections:
    connection.send(b"hello") # the b changes the string to bytes
```